# Variable doesn't want to get defined, and general advice

Tags: python

just casually learning python over here and trying to write fizzbuzz. I'm reading a book to get me going but just want to try out stuff myself because I think that's going to work out the best for me as it generally does when learning stuff. So this is what I've got:

```
def input_and_test():
    print "Gimme something and it better be a number or shit ain't gon work"
    inputt = raw_input()
    inputt = str(inputt)

    try:
        input_data_type = int(inputt)
    except ValueError:
        print "Yeah that sure as hell ain't a number, sonny"
        input_and_test()
    else:
        print 'Great, now lemme check'

input_and_test()

input_lenght = len(inputt)
input_lenght = int(int(input_lenght) - 1)
last_number = inputt[input_lenght]

if input == 1:
    print 'Even'
elif last_number == 0 or last_number == 2 or last_number == 4 or last_number == 6 or last_number == 8:
    print 'Even'
else:
    print 'Odd'
```

Now I'm sure this is horribly inefficient but that doesn't matter because I want to learn how to do it this 'way'. It throws this error though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    input_lenght = len(inputt)
NameError: name 'inputt' is not defined
```

Why? Did I not define inputt in the first function that I just called? Is there a better way to replace the exception handling and start the function again part that fixes all of this? Any bad things about this code (apart from it not being optimal fizzbuzz) that I should avoid in the future? Again sorry for this being hilariously bad and this question being hilariously simple probably. I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Variables defined in a function are not visible outside the function, unless you declare them with `global`.

Comment: You should try to avoid using global variables. Functions should get their input from parameters, and use `return` to return data to the caller.

Comment: Make sure you post your code with correct indentation. Since Python uses indentation to parse the structure of the code, we need to see how you have the code indented to understand it.

Comment: Read up on variable "scope"

Comment: thanks, so what do you recommend I do? have everything in one main function so the variable is already 'global', but I could still add something after this one function? code is also indented correctly, here a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/HHrKdKUM

Comment: okay thanks, I'll look into that dstudeba. seems like the correct way to do something like this. are there any negatives to global variables like this?

Comment: and here's an edited pastebin: http://pastebin.com/aXCKxZLf (but beware of the way you're trying to get the length of a number, which probably won't do what you want, and are using `if input` instead of `if inputt` near the end...)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - Since his `inputt` variable is actually a *string* and not an int, what he's doing would work. You're right about the misspelled `input` variable near the end, which should have been `inputt`.

Comment: thanks people, I completely understand now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Barmar said in a comment, you should really use `return` to get your function's output out into the calling code. Here's how you could have written your function better with `return`:

```
def input_and_test():
    print "Gimme something and it better be a number or shit ain't gon work"
    inputt = raw_input()
    inputt = str(inputt)

    try:
        input_data_type = int(inputt)
    except ValueError:
        print "Yeah that sure as hell ain't a number, sonny"
        return input_and_test()
    else:
        print 'Great, now lemme check'
        return inputt

inputt = input_and_test()

input_lenght = len(inputt)
input_lenght = int(int(input_lenght) - 1)
last_number = inputt[input_lenght]

if input == 1:
    print 'Even'
elif last_number == 0 or last_number == 2 or last_number == 4 or last_number == 6 or last_number == 8:
    print 'Even'
else:
    print 'Odd'
```

In the code above, I've left your variable names alone, with the name `inputt` being used in two places. But that might confuse you, because the `inputt` *inside* the function is not the same variable as the `inputt` *outside* the function. So I'll rename your inside-the-function variable to a different name (personally, I like using the name `result` for "the value that this function is eventually going to return), so that it will be easier for you to see what's going on:

```
def input_and_test():
    print "Gimme something and it better be a number or shit ain't gon work"
    result = raw_input()
    result = str(result)

    try:
        input_data_type = int(result)
    except ValueError:
        print "Yeah that sure as hell ain't a number, sonny"
        return input_and_test()
    else:
        print 'Great, now lemme check'
        return result

inputt = input_and_test()

input_lenght = len(inputt)
input_lenght = int(int(input_lenght) - 1)
last_number = inputt[input_lenght]

if input == 1:
    print 'Even'
elif last_number == 0 or last_number == 2 or last_number == 4 or last_number == 6 or last_number == 8:
    print 'Even'
else:
    print 'Odd'
```

There, now the two different variables have two different names.

Now, do you see how I have two different `return` statements in the function? Is it obvious to you why, or do you need me to expand on this answer to explain why the `return input_and_test()` line is necessary?

Comment: Ah, this is much cleaner. You set inputt to what the fucntion outputs; makes sense. The only thing I don't get is how it knows to start over if the ValueError gets raised. edit: oh never mind, returning the function will make it call itself again. Thanks a lot, I get it now!

Comment: @applepieftw - Short version: it calls `input_and_test()` a second time, which is an example of *recursion*. (See http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php for an explanation of recursion, or Google "recursion" if you need more examples.) And since whatever the *inner* call returns will immediately be returned by the *outer* call, this is pretty much the equivalent of saying "just go back to the beginning and try again". The term for this is "tail recursion", but that's a more advanced topic that you should tackle at a later date.

Comment: Yup I knew that was recursion, but I'll get around to how exactly the inner and outer functions work like you suggested eventually. Trying this and then getting help here was very... helpful and fun. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the value from your function.

At the end of `input_and_test` add:

```
return inputt
```

Then, in every place where you call `input_and_test`, store the value:

```
inputt = input_and_test()
```

You have to do that because `inputt` is local variable inside `input_and_test`, so each time you call that function, a new `inputt` variable is created inside it. Once the function exits, the variable is gone.

Comment: There's another place where he'd need a `return` statement, as I pointed out in my answer. The `except ValueError` block where he recurses would also need a `return` statement, otherwise he'll be implicitly returning `None` if that `except` block is ever run.

Comment: @rmunn actually, if he stores to `inputt` in except and then returns `inputt` at the end (not in else, after it), then it still works. that is what i had in mind. but your solution is also correct.